# Failed to install swifter via pip - INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions .. compatible with other requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, swifter

Within my virtual `python 3.9x` - environment on my `Lubuntu 20.04` - System, I tried to install `swifter` via command line using `pip install swifter`.
This doesn't work out however, as the compatibility checks with several modules, such as `jupyter-core`, `jupyter-client`, `jedi` and `decorator` cannot be finished even after 1 hour running time.

The entire stdout of `pip install swifter` until interrupting the process forcefully via `CTRL + C` can be seen in what follows:

```
Collecting swifter
  Using cached swifter-1.0.7.tar.gz (633 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0.0 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from swifter) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.33.0 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from swifter) (4.54.1)
Collecting bleach>=3.1.1
  Using cached bleach-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from bleach>=3.1.1->swifter) (1.15.0)
Collecting dask[dataframe]>=2.10.0
  Using cached dask-2.30.0-py3-none-any.whl (848 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0.0 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from swifter) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.0 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dask[dataframe]>=2.10.0->swifter) (1.19.4)
Collecting fsspec>=0.6.0
  Using cached fsspec-0.8.4-py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
Collecting ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2
  Using cached ipywidgets-8.0.0a0-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
Collecting ipykernel>=4.5.1
  Using cached ipykernel-5.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (120 kB)
Collecting ipython>=6.1.0
  Using cached ipython-7.19.0-py3-none-any.whl (784 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (50.3.2)
Collecting backcall
  Using cached backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting decorator
  Using cached decorator-4.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
Collecting jedi>=0.10
  Using cached jedi-0.17.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
Collecting jupyter-client
  Using cached jupyter_client-6.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (108 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
Collecting jupyter-core>=4.6.0
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting modin[ray]>=0.8.1.1
  Using cached modin-0.8.2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (533 kB)
  Using cached modin-0.8.1.1-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (538 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jupyter-core to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting jupyter-core>=4.6.0
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jupyter-client to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting jupyter-client
  Using cached jupyter_client-6.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (108 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jupyter-core to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached jupyter_client-6.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (107 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
  Using cached jupyter_client-6.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (106 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-6.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (106 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-6.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (106 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (106 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-6.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jupyter-client to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (92 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (92 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
Collecting jupyter-core
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting jupyter-client
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
  Using cached jupyter_client-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_client-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_client-4.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_client-4.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_client-4.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_client-4.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_client-4.1.0.zip (270 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_client-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jedi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting jedi>=0.10
  Using cached jedi-0.17.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /home/andylu/.virtualenvs/WWTP_Camping_San_Fernando/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=7.0.0cloudpickle>=0.2.2->swifter) (2.8.1)
....
```

As a side note on the previous lengthy code-block: I tried to make foldable markdown/HTML-blocks work here as suggested in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303150/869131), but it is not enabled by the stackoverflow - engine at the moment.